# d3.js Collapsible Tree node should drop on first parent or child (+1 or -1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web, d3.js

Working on **D3.js Drag and Drop, Zoomable, Panning, Collapsible Tree, I want node element to be drop on exact parent or child node i.e (+1 or -1) i have tried various conditions but not fulfilling.

Currently it drag-drop on any node.

here is an example `[http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/8wYfu/][1]`

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You would have to modify the function called on dragend to take this condition into account.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I have tried changes there only here is code can you please tell me what is wrong:

`if (Math.abs(selectedNode.depth - draggingNode.depth) <=  2) {
     sortTree();
     endDrag();
      return
                }`

Comment: but this condition prevents to drop on any node though i want it to drop on +1 and -1 @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Have you checked whether those values are what you expect them to be?